# iOS line in via headphone jack (adapter?)

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to record an audio signal with my Audio Unit on my iPhone which comes from a normal 3.5mm audio cable (e.g. with another iPhone acting as sound source).

A direct line-in is not possible, because the iPhone has a 4 port headphone jack.
I tried different kinds of these adapters:
[http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-headsets-separate-headphone-microphone/dp/B004SP0WAQ/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1446196112&sr=8-3&keywords=3.5mm+headphone+mic+splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004SP0WAQ)

But none of these worked.

Am I doing something wrong?
What else could I try?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match the expected impedance for the microphone.  Otherwise the device treats it as if it weren't there.  Check [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/electronic-aspects-of-iphone-3-5mm-audio-output) out for details.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and will mark your answer as correct if it works!